# Integrating wave equation with Runge-Kutta (2nd order)

Tags: c++, numerical-integration, runge-kutta

I try to solve numerically simple equation - linear wave equation with no sources: u<sub>tt</sub> = v<sup>2</sup> u<sub>xx</sub>

where v - velocity of wave.

I use initial conditions:

u(x, 0) = sin(x)
u<sub>x</sub>(x, 0) = -v * sin(x)

which correspond to initial wave sin(x) propagating with velocity v along x-axis (sin(x-vt) is a solution of this wave equation).

So, the problem is that during 2-3 iterations numerical solution coincides with analytical answer (sin(x-vt)), but after 3rd iteration something goes wrong and solution grows high very fast (takes values about 128).

I use Runge-Kutta 2nd oreder method (Euler method) with 4-order approximation of 2nd derivative.

Here's a code on C++:

```
//2nd derivative function

float z2der(int n, int i, int j, float* x, float** zx)
{
    float h = x[2] - x[1];
    float zr, zl, zm, zrr, zll;

    zm = -30.0 * zx[i][j];
    if (i < n - 1)
        zr = 16.0 * zx[i + 1][j];
    else
        zr = 16.0;
    if (i > 0)
        zl = 16.0 * zx[i - 1][j];
    else
        zl = 16.0;
    if (i < n - 2)
        zrr = -zx[i + 2][j];
    else
        zrr = 1.0; //CHECK
    if (i > 1)
        zll = -zx[i - 2][j];

    if (i > 1 && i < n - 2)
        return (zll + zrr + zl + zr + zm) / (12.0 * h * h);
    if (i == 1)
        return (15 / 4 * zx[i][j] - 77 / 6 * zx[i + 1][j] - 107 / 6 * zx[i + 2][j] - 13 * zx[i + 3][j] - 61 / 12 * zx[i + 4][j]) / (h*h);
    if (i == n - 2)
        return (15 / 4 * zx[i][j] - 77 / 6 * zx[i - 1][j] - 107 / 6 * zx[i - 2][j] - 13 * zx[i - 3][j] - 61 / 12 * zx[i - 4][j]) / (h*h);
    if (i == 0 || i == n - 1)
        return 0;
}


//PARAMETERS

float tmin = 0.0;
float tmax = 12.0;
int nt = 37000;
float dt = (tmax - tmin) / float(nt);
float *time = new float[nt];
for (int j = 0; j < nt; j++)
    time[j] = tmin + dt * float(j);

float xmin = -30.0;
float xmax = 30.0;
int nx = 901;
float *x = new float[nx];
for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    x[i] = xmin + (xmax - xmin) * float(i) / float(nx);

float v = -0.1; // velocity

float** wave = new float*[nx];
for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    wave[i] = new float[nt];

float** waved = new float*[nx];
for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    waved[i] = new float[nt];

for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
{
    xx = x[i];
    wave[i][0] = sin(xx);
    waved[i][0] = -v * v * sin(xx);
}

float* wavedd = new float[nx];
float* waveddot = new float[nx];

for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) //j=0;
{
    wavedd[i] = z2der(nx, i, 0, x, wave);
    waveddot[i] = v * v * wavedd[i];
}

for (int j = 0; j < nt - 1; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    {
        waved[i][j + 1] = waved[i][j] + dt * waveddot[i];
        wave[i][j + 1] = wave[i][j] + dt * waved[i][j];

        wavedd[i] = z2der(nx, i, j + 1, x, wave);
        waveddot[i] = v * v * wavedd[i];
    }
}
```

So, I don't know why is it going wrong and what the reason is.

Comment: Numerical code is debugged much like ordinary code. Does it work for simpler inputs? Don't try sines if f(x)=0 already fails. Also, don't post two functions if you can localize the bug in one. Does your `z2der` function actually give you the second derivative?

Answer (score 3):

All of your RK tableau values are going to have a problem because you are doing integer division

```
return (15 / 4 * ...
```

Due to operator precedence this will evaluate to

```
return (3 * ...
```

You need to work entirely in `double`

```
return (15.0 / 4.0 * ...
```

Comment: Okay, I overlooked this, thanks. Now I fixed it, but it still works wrong (almost like it worked before).